# xCode 4.5 Create static library: can't copy source files into library destination folder

Tags: xcode, ios6, static-libraries, xcode4.5

I just want to create a static library for iOS.
I followed the instructions written in the documentation:
[Creating the Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW1)

I run the latest version of xCode (4.5, 4G182).
I'm experiencing an error in adding existing project folder to my library because I miss the "Copy items into destination group's folder" checkmark when the adding dialog shows.
Is it an xCode 4.5 bug? Did I miss something?

I see this:
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try to copy all files/folders to project directory, then add then to project.

Answer (score -1):

How are you importing your static library?  If you drag and drop the static library from your finder into your project navigator, then you should get the option to copy items into destination's group folder.

Comment: Not sure who gave the downvote but this answer is correct.  There are many ways to import a static library, dragging it into the project navigator is one way and will give you the dialog box that the OP is looking for.